# Sort a list of strings by their lengths

Tags: python, list

```
words = ["dog", "apple", "bear"]
def len_words(words):
        w1 = []
      for p in words:
          w1.append(len(p))
          pass
for p in words:
       words.sort(key=len_words)
```

I tried to sort by this code. But my result is the same list as given input. It isn't sorted.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
words = ["dog", "apple", "bear"]    
words.sort(key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to define your own length function, just use `key=len` to sort by length using the [built-in `len` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html);

```
>>> words = ["dog", "apple", "bear"]
>>> words.sort(key=len)
>>> words
['dog', 'bear', 'apple']
```