# python format string by length

Tags: python

I have some strings below:

```
123123|00|992|1111
222222|2222|19|922
997997|3333|922|77
```

How can I format like this (sort by len):

```
123123|1111|00|992
222222|2222|19|922
997997|3333|77|922
```

Comment: I'm confused. If you're sorting by len, why does 00 come before 992?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list of strings by their lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299988/sort-a-list-of-strings-by-their-lengths)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.split` & `str.join` with `sorted`

**Demo:**

```
s = """123123|00|992|1111
222222|2222|19|922
997997|3333|922|77"""

data = ["|".join(sorted(i.split("|"), key=len, reverse=True)) for i in s.split("\n")]
print( "\n".join(data) )
```

**Output:**

```
123123|1111|992|00
222222|2222|922|19
997997|3333|922|77
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a='''123123|00|992|1111
222222|2222|19|922
997997|3333|922|77'''
'\n'.join(['|'.join(sorted(e.split("|"),key=len,reverse=True)) for e in a.split("\n")])
```

Output:

```
123123|1111|992|00
222222|2222|922|19
997997|3333|922|77
```

Answer (score 1):

The OPs sort order isn't based on string length, as the length of 2 comes before the length of 3 (the very last two segments)

for that purpose, a custom sort mapping is needed

```
ranks = {6:0, 4:1, 2:2, 3:3}
text = """123123|00|992|1111
222222|2222|19|922
997997|3333|922|77"""

result = '\n'.join(['|'.join(sorted(line.split('|'),key=lambda x: ranks[len(x)])) 
                    for line in text.split('\n')])
print(result)
# outputs:
123123|1111|00|992
222222|2222|19|922
997997|3333|77|922
```